# Sharepoint 2007 isn't compatible with infopath 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

it's just a simple question. Currently i have microsoft office 2010 "Infopath 2010", i manage to upload the file in our sharepoint service 2007, but, whenever someone from another office tries to open it, it pops out this error.

[image: SoapÂction]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use InfoPath 2010 with SharePoint 2007 to design form templates (with or without code) for publishing on SharePoint 2007, but must remember to first set the compatibility.

InfoPath 2010 offers 5 form types for compatibility with the latest and previous versions of InfoPath:

1. Web Browser Form
2. InfoPath Filler Form
3. Web Browser Form (InfoPath 2007)
4. InfoPath 2007 Filler Form
5. InfoPath 2003 Filler Form

You can go to File > Info > Form Options > Compatibility and change the Form type.

http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2010/10/use-infopath-2010-design-form-templates-sharepoint-2007/